# Selenium cambiar ventana handles cuando se cierra

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

El prolema que tengo es que cuando accedo a la pagina en concreto me tengo que conectar con una extencion de google y me pide user y pass.

Hasta ahi todo correcto pero cuando nesesito pedir confirmacion se habre la ventana nuevamente pero ah esa ventana no puedo acceder.

Aca les dejo parte del codigo para que me comprendan.

Hasta aca  todo perfecto.

```
driver.get(url)

driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div/input')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/button/span').click()
driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])
```

Este es el codigo en concreto

```
def Aceptar():
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[3]/footer/button[2]')
    driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])
```

Este es el error en concreto(El error esta en esta linea: driver.switch_to.window(handles[1]) en el codigo de arriba)

````
Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window```
````